# Javascript regex for allowing only positive digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I use this to test for digits

```
/^\d+$/
```

But I need to make sure that it's greater than zero, while still allowing 0000123123123 for instance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can write:

```
/^\d*[1-9]\d*$/
```

(zero or more digits, followed by a nonzero digit, followed by zero or more digits).

Answer (score 6):

It is correct regex for positive digits.

```
 /^[1-9]\d*$/g
```

The previous answer not correct for 0123.